# R - Regression plane for linear mixed-effects model with 3 explicative variables

Tags: r, regression, plane

I'm struggling to plot the regression plane of a linear mixed-effects model with 3 explicative variables. I used the code [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization#regression-plane), which is for a z~x+y model, and tried to adapt it for a z~x+y+c model :

```
library(nlme)
library(plot3D)

data <- read.table('data-plot-3D.csv', dec=',', sep=';', header=TRUE)    

test <- lme(z~x+y+c,
            data=data,
            random=~1|s, method="ML")

grid.lines = nrow(data)
x.pred <- seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = grid.lines)
y.pred <- seq(min(data$y), max(data$y), length.out = grid.lines)
c.pred <- seq(min(data$c), max(data$c), length.out = grid.lines)

xyc <- expand.grid(x=x.pred, 
                   y=y.pred, 
                   c=c.pred)

z.pred <- matrix(predict(test, newdata=xyc, level=0), 
                  nrow=grid.lines, ncol=grid.lines)

fitpoints <- as.vector(predict(test, data))

scatter3D(data$x, data$y, data$z, 
          pch=18, cex=2, theta=20, phi=20, ticktype="detailed",
          xlab="x", ylab = "y", zlab="z",  
          surf=list(x=x.pred,
                    y=y.pred,
                    z=z.pred,
                    facets = NA,
                    fit = fitpoints),
          main="Model 3D plot")
```

But the figure is wrong : the plane does not fit at all. I have several hypothesis that could explain this result, for example the `level=0` parameter when it comes to predict values, or some properties of linear mixed-effects models that I don't know. If I understood correctly, the `level=0` parameter is needed because the lme model includes some noise and my plotting data do not consider it (maybe I'm wrong).

When I simplify the model to a simple linear model (`lm` instead of `lme`), with a removal of the 3d variable (`z~x+y`), I have a correct regression plane :

```
library(nlme)
library(plot3D)

data <- read.table('data-plot-3D.csv', dec=',', sep=';', header=TRUE)

test <- lm(z~x+y, data=data)

grid.lines = nrow(data)
x.pred <- seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = grid.lines)
y.pred <- seq(min(data$y), max(data$y), length.out = grid.lines)

xy <- expand.grid(x=x.pred, 
                  y=y.pred)

z.pred <- matrix(predict(test, newdata=xy), 
                 nrow=grid.lines, ncol=grid.lines)

fitpoints <- predict(test)

scatter3D(data$x, data$y, data$z, 
          pch=18, cex=2, theta=20, phi=20, ticktype="detailed",
          xlab="senescence", ylab = "cambium", zlab="budburst",  
          surf=list(x=x.pred,
                    y=y.pred,
                    z=z.pred,
                    facets = NA,
                    fit = fitpoints),
          main="Good plane (lm z~x+y)")
```

How can I solve that problem ? The data and the pictures are below. I have also planned to color the points and the plane according to the `c` variable instead of along the  `z` axis, but I guess it is less important (I'll ask another question maybe)

```
s;z;x;y;c
B;103,5104;259,9426;250;0,289661996
F;100,6323;292,9711;250;0,522028213
F;105,2674;293,2956;257;0,429718346
F;103,2945;289,3861;257;0,499746521
B;100,3786;283,8451;271;0,210084525
B;100,392;284,7398;271;0,261014107
F;106,0284;295,9574;271;0,674816959
F;105,2831;280,6875;271;0,592056388
F;109,1873;284,9641;271;0,607971883
B;100,1647;253,8401;271;0,327859183
B;100,1124;259,4129;271;0,270563403
B;101,2346;261,3593;271;0,238732415
B;100,9574;285,814;277;0,261014107
F;105,1347;294,102;277;0,461549335
B;102,3565;302,9692;277;0,33422538
F;102,6884;297,6776;284;0,410619753
F;109,0465;288,4876;284;0,44881694
Q;110,0359;318,2187;284;0,630253575
Q;108,2855;285,7081;311;0,413802852
F;113,5328;308,7703;311;0,385154962
F;105,1965;266,3839;311;0,585690191
Q;112,9197;314,6168;311;0,604788784
Q;105,5601;284,8472;311;0,506112719
Q;109,5241;309,2628;319;0,36287327
Q;109,5802;315,2328;319;0,461549335
F;108,3161;285,0408;319;0,397887358
Q;110,3092;317,1796;328;0,423352149
Q;110,5984;297,9926;328;0,620704278
```

[image: wrong plane]

[image: good plane]